# jquery - How to populate multiple divs with multiple buttons (help me simplify)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to populate multiple divs on the same page. Half the divs have class="currentRhythmA", and half the divs have class="currentRhythmB". These divs will be populated by a user's choice from 100 unique one-measure rhythms, each of which appears as an image, with corresponding audio file and text label. Each rhythm has an id, which might be something like "RM-1.1" or "RM-6.12". By clicking on the rhythm's label (which has a class of "button" in the Rhythm A section and "buttonB" in the Rhythm B section), the user can choose one rhythm for Rhythm A and one rhythm for Rhythm B.

I have two questions:
QUESTION 1. I have succeeded in filling multiple divs with the same rhythm, but I've used ids instead of classes, which seems inefficient. How do I convert this code to fill divs with a class of "currentRhythmA" rather than the long list of ids? I tried replacing #currentRhythmA, #AAAA-1, etc., with .currentRhythmA (again, all these ids share a class of currentRhythmA), but it didn't work.

```
$( function() {
    $( '.button' ).click(function() {   
        var postData = '';  
        $.ajax( {
            url : 'js/ajax_file_A.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : postData,                
            success : function( resp ) {
                $('#currentRhythmA').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AAAA-1').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AAAA-2').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AAAA-3').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AAAA-4').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AAAB-1').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AAAB-2').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AAAB-3').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AABA-1').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AABA-2').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AABA-4').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AABB-1').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#AABB-2').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#ABAA-1').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#ABAA-3').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#ABAA-4').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#ABAB-1').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#ABAB-3').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#ABBA-1').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#ABBA-4').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#ABBB-1').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BAAA-2').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BAAA-3').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BAAA-4').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BAAB-2').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BAAB-3').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BABA-2').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BABA-4').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BABB-2').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BBAA-3').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BBAA-4').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BBAB-3').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                $('#BBBA-4').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());

            }
        });
           return false;
    });
});
```

CONTENTS OF ajax_file_A.php:

```
    <div> <!-- Container div -->

            <div id="measureA">
            <img src="images/RM-3.2.png">
            </div>

    </div>
```

QUESTION 2. As you can see from the contents of the AJAX file, I've figured out how to set ONE button (the one corresponding to RM-3.2) to fill the divs. But I have 100 buttons, each with a unique ID but a shared class of "button". How do I write code to make EVERY button workable? (I am guessing I use getElementById, but I don't know how to do it!)

You can look at the actual site in process, if that's helpful... [www.freescaling.com/rhythmetrics](http://www.yayforeverything.com/freescaling/rhythmetrics) (click the "select your rhythms" button).

Whoops, let me update my original post with the code for the buttons. Each button is coded like this:

```
    <div class="RM_rhythm">
        <audio id="5.1" preload='none'>
           <source src='audio/RM-beat.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/RM-beat.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />
        </audio>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('5.1').play()">&#x25b6;</button>
        <a href="#" class="button">5-1</a>
            <img src="images/RM-5.1.png" width="172" height="67" alt="5-1">
    </div>
```

As you can see, the button "5-1" calls the image file "RM-5.1.png". Button "6-12", similarly, calls image file "RM-6.12.png". Right now, because of the code in my ajax file, EVERY button calls image file "RM-3.2.png". How can I instruct each button to call its own corresponding image file? Many thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ? I guess calling `.html()` on a collection of elements cannot work. This way, you can call `html()` on each element in the `$('.currentRhythmA')` collection :

```
$( function() {
    $( '.button' ).click(function() {   
        var postData = '';  
        $.ajax( {
            url : 'js/ajax_file_A.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : postData,                
            success : function( resp ) {
                $('.currentRhythmA').each(function () {
                    $(this).html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, sodawillow! The error was mine to begin with... I'd typed "currentRhythmA" in one place and "currentRhythm_A" in another. The simple substitution of ".currentRhythmA" for "#currentRhythmA" worked.

Answer (score 0):

question 1: for classes, you use the jquery uses syntax `.myClass` (ids use `#myId`) so in this case, you would do:

```
$('.currentRhythmA').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
```

question 2: you already have the code for the buttons if all have them class `button` because you used the class syntax of `$('.button')`.

if you are adding the buttons onto the DOM and see that they dont trigger your `.click()` function, use `$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {});` instead of just `$('.button').click(function() {});`

**EDIT:**

so you can use this general concept of using the classes and `.closest()` and `.find()` to find out the id and call the image

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('audio').attr('id'); 
        // finds id by finding the .RM_rhythm div that its in and the id of the audio element
        $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src", 'images/RM-' + id + '.png');
        // finds the image within the .RM_rhythm div that its in and assigns the src to call the image
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="RM_rhythm">
    <audio id="5.1" preload='none'>
        <source src='audio/RM-beat.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/RM-beat.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />
    </audio>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('5.1').play()">&#x25b6;</button>
    <a href="#" class="button">5-1</a>
    <img src="" width="172" height="67" alt="5-1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, indubitalee. You're right about the answer for question 1. I had tried it, but I'd typed "currentRhythm_A" rather than "currentRhythmA." Doh! It's working now.

Comment: As for question 2: The button functionality works, but right now I have it coded to fill with ONE rhythm... no matter which button I press, ".currentRhythmA" fills with RM-3.2png (as specified in my ajax_file_A.php). What I'm trying to figure out is how to code each buttons to call its own corresponding image file.

Comment: I have updated my original post to add the code for the buttons.

Comment: @jennykat, updated my answer according to your button code.

Comment: Indubitablee, you are a font of wisdom! Your commented code is so helpful. May I beg you for one more hint? I now need to combine your two snippets of code, so that once the ID is found and the image is called, it then fills the ".currentRhythmA" divs. Can you help me understand how to combine the two functions? Thanks again, so much.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, just add `$('.currentRhythmA').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());` after `$(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src", 'images/RM-' + id + '.png');`. if that doesnt do what youre looking to do, sorry for the misunderstanding and could you clarify more with what your intended functionality is?

Comment: it's not working, but I think I'm almost there. I wonder if the problem is that I'm asking it to fill '.currentRhythmA' with '#measureA', when actually I need it to fill '.currentRhythmA' with the found id that results from your code above...

Comment: can you help me troubleshoot? How can I set the value of the found id to #measureA (or what should I sub for "#measureA" in the following code)? Here's what I have now: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('audio').attr('id'); 
        $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src", 'images/RM-' + id + '.png');
        $('.currentRhythmA').html($('#measureA' , resp).html());
    });
});`

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with the last line? with the html replacement?

Comment: I am trying to replace .currentRhythmA with the image that's called by the button click .

Comment: thank you SO much for your help. With your code and the tweaks of a friend of mine, I got it working. Here's the final code: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        var imagewanted = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src");
        $('.currentRhythm_A').html("<img src='" + imagewanted + "' />");
    });
});`